# How to find packages recently uploaded to the Ubuntu repository

Tags: mirrors, reprepro

I've recently used reprepro to set up a mirror of the official Ubuntu repository for one architecture and one release (Precise in this case). Please note how in `conf/distributions` I define one repository that the clients on my network will reference and in `conf/updates` I pull all components into it (including updates and security). If doing it this way (everything pulled into a single local repository) isn't a good practice, I'm open to suggestions (I haven't mirrored Ubuntu before).

However - I know that in order to keep the repository up to date, it is suggested that we pull in changes from the upstream every 6 hours (exactly as for Debian). I don't know how often the updated packages are uploaded to the upstream repos and that's probably the reason why I'm worried that the local repo update might be missing some packages that had already been uploaded to the upstream.

I'd like to get a list of packages recently uploaded to the upstream to verify whether my mirror is working correctly and the message I'm getting during the local repository update:

> Nothing to do found. (Use --noskipold to force processing)

Isn't anything to be worried about. Is it safe to just rely on the fact that if the Release.gpg isn't changed since the last pull, there's really nothing to do? Is there a way to find such list/history of uploads?

Here's my reprepro repository configuration:

conf/distributions:

```
Origin: Ubuntu
Label: Ubuntu
Suite: precise
Version: 12.04
Codename: precise
Architectures: amd64
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Description: Ubuntu Precise 12.04 + updates + security
Update: - precise precise-updates precise-security
Log: update.log
```

conf/updates:

```
Name: precise
Architectures: amd64
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Method: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
VerifyRelease: 40976EAF437D05B5

Name: precise-updates
Architectures: amd64
Suite: precise-updates
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Method: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
VerifyRelease: 40976EAF437D05B5

Name: precise-security
Architectures: amd64
Suite: precise-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Method: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
VerifyRelease: 40976EAF437D05B5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been running the repository mirror for a few weeks now and carried out a few tests and it hasn't missed fetching any updated packages since each time a package is uploaded to the upstream repository, the Release and Release.gpg files are updated and reprepro compares the local and upstream version.